# Constexpr function as template parameter for SFINAE

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, constexpr, enable-if

Could anyone clarify why the following does not work:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

template<typename T, typename U>
constexpr bool is_same_fn()
{
    return std::is_same_v<T, U>;
}

template<typename T, std::enable_if_t<is_same_fn<T, int>(), bool> = true>
void fn2() { std::cout << "True mg\n"; }

template<typename T, std::enable_if_t<!is_same_fn<T, int>(), bool> = true>
void fn2() { std::cout << "False mg\n"; }

int main() {
    fn2<int>();
    fn2<char>();
    return 0;
}
```

Note that the same thing compiles if rather than using the function, I use directly `std::is_same` instead as a template parameter.

The errors that I get are:

```
error C2995:  'void fn2(void)': function template has already been defined
message :  see declaration of 'fn2'
error C3861:  'fn2': identifier not found
```

The language standard is properly set to: `ISO C++17 Standard (/std:c++17)`.
This happens on MSVC 2019, version 16.1.6

Comment: What compiler, version and command line?  This works for me, see: https://wandbox.org/permlink/7cMUXjWcIslirGqe (needs C++17)

Comment: @PaulSanders I assumed it was not supposed to work. I used msvc, I'll link a godbolt link a second.

Comment: MSVC v19 compiles it just fine: https://godbolt.org/z/pXveE-

Comment: @PaulSanders MSVC 2019, v16.1.6. As mentioned by alterigel godbolt seems to compile it just fine, so I guess it's a compiler bug then.

Comment: @alterigel Not the desktop version that I have MSVC 2019, v16.1.6. Afaik that's the latest community edition version, since it doesn't let me update to anything newer.

Comment: This works fine for me in MSVC 2017 15.6.7.  Did you specify C++17 in the property pages for your project (C/C++ -> Language -> C++ Language Standard)?  MS are working hard on compliance and hopefully have not gone backwards.

Comment: It would help if you included your compiler errors and any related compiler options you changed

Comment: @PaulSanders Doesn't work on my MSVC unfortunately (`/std:c++17` is set), it would be great if somebody could try and reproduce this.

Comment: Perhaps report it to MS (Menu -> Help -> Send Feedback -> Report a Problem).  They will probably be pleased to hear about it.

Comment: @PaulSanders Just tested with my VS2017 version - works just fine. I guess they've indeed gone backwards. I'll report it alright, that's the 4th compiler bug within the week ;(

Comment: As a note, when compiling code with MSVC, I would suggest testing SFINAE errors with another compiler (Clang or GCC work best for this, IMO), either on your system or using an online tool like Godbolt or Coliru.  MSVC has a history of struggling with SFINAE, particularly with determining whether two functions that differ only by, e.g., `enable_if` condition, are distinct.  (In the past, they recommended adding an additional dummy parameter to one version but not the other, as a workaround until they can get it working properly.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They seem to have fixed it after I reported it:

> A fix for this issue has been released in 16.2 Preview 3!

Answer (score -1):

The two functions have the same signature, the only difference is the default template argument. To overload a function, the overloads must take different arguments.

Instead of making two separate functions, you can make one function (not SFINAEd) and use a `if constexpr` in the body.

Comment: The code provided here is simply a minimal example to illustrate the compiler bug. I am using this for an entirely different purpose in practice, where an `if constexpr` doesn't cut it (I need to be able to hide a function through SFINAE). The problem that I face in practice is not insurmountable without constexpr functions as template parameters either, it's just that it's a lot uglier without those.

Comment: This is not a compiler bug. You cannot have two functions with the same name that take the same arguments.

Comment: This is a compiler bug. It works just fine in VS2017, gcc, godbolt etc. The condition in `enable_if_t` hides one of the functions when the condition is satisfied/not satisfied. I may have as well used `std::is_same_v<T,int>` and it would have worked in this example.